# Inter-server communication via known ports

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq, .net-remoting

Our product system consists of an IIS 6.0 server, behind which is a Java SOA server, behind both of which is an Oracle database server.

For various reasons, we need a windows service running on the Java SOA server that stores opaque blobs associated with GUIDs. Here is a simplified version of the interface:

```
interface IBlobService
{
    void PutBlob(Guid key, byte[] data);
    byte[] GetBlob(Guid key);
}
```

The main user of the IBlobService is the web front-end running on the IIS server. We could use WCF or .NET remoting over a custom port for communication between the servers. However, our application is subject to strict accreditation requirements. We would highly prefer to use a known port for communication, rather than a custom port.

We can't use named pipes, because we need to communicate between the servers.
We had considered using MSMQ, as it uses a known port, but MSMQ limits message size to 4 MB. We need to transfer far more than that -- up to 60 MB at least.

**What other capabilities (if any) does .NET expose that would allow communication between servers via a known port?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* MSMQ is the facility of choice, I would chunk the data and reassemble it.

The contents of your message body is opaque, so including with each chunk data such as id, sequence, size, and a CRC is all possible.

You might want to consider WCF binary streams.  See this article from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using WCF you could use HTTP/HTPS.  You could also use raw tcp on whatever port you like. e.g. just because port 80 is the standard http port doesn't mean you cannot run some other protocol on that port, so long as the server isn't using it already.

Comment: That is a good point, but we can't use HTTP, and HTTPS is already bound by the Java application server.

Comment: You could use https on a non standard port that is below 1024. e.g. port 25, pretend you are sending 60Mb emails ;-)

Comment: We probably will use SSL regardless of which port we use, but I'd like to use a known port that is intended for our desired use. MSMQ seemed like a great option, but alas -- the message size limitation!

Comment: Could you split your blobs into smaller chunks then reassemble them at the other end.  If you can change the interface then you could add a sequence parameter, if not you could stick an extra byte at the beginning and use it as the sequence.

Comment: Chunking large messages is a standard approach and been around since almost day 1. If you send the chunks within a transaction then they all reach the remote queue in order.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not address the problem in the question but presents an alternative approach that avoids the problem.

After deliberation, it is not a requirement that the blob service run as a windows service. Instead, a plain Java servlet that implements a RESTful interface to the data could be hosted in the Java application server. This would bypass the SOAP stack and XML overhead, yet leverage the supervisory capability of the Java application server.

Data can be stored with a

```
PUT https://java-app-server.example.com/blobService/b12a0403-... HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: <LENGTH OF BLOB>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<BLOB>
```

And later retrieved with a

```
GET https://java-app-server.example.com/blobService/b12a0403-... HTTP/1.1
```

Which returns

```
Content-Length: <LENGTH OF BLOB>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<BLOB>
```

Comment: [JSR 315](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) is the Servlet 3.0 spec, which allows asynchronous servlets. It's implemented in Java EE 6. That would be a boon for performance!